# Add image to dropdown menu

Tags: cms

I have the theme, theme was applied (So I think? I've taken over this project from a partner) to the site and I'm using mega menu. In my menu I have ha dropdown menu for a specific category. In this dropdown I want to be able to have a picture in the bottom of the dropdown, [like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiOpH.jpg).

In my manage categories tab [I have these options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS1zO.jpg), and everywhere where I'm able to upload images it doesn't show in my dropdown.

How do I fix this?

Comment: According to the screenshot, you need to create static block and assign that to your category under theme options and also there should be an option for position.

Comment: @SukumarGorai I've created a static block under CMS tab. I named it "megamenu_catid_2" (My dropdown menu has ID 2). https://imgur.com/a/4T3pXiA

And then I assign it in "Manage Category" > Display Settings. https://imgur.com/a/ysLXuvB

But nothing happens

Comment: Thats fine. Did you assign that to your category. I am seeing that on category there is a tab for theme vast, Can you check there is you need to assign that static block and postion of that static block or not?

Comment: This is under the tab theme vast. Here I can't assign the static block, but I can upload an image, which does not show in the menu https://imgur.com/a/EcB8592 
I'm also not sure if I've assigned the static block to the category or not. What I showed in the other screenshots is all I've done

Comment: Bottom content is for the image. Did you upload banner_content2.jpg? Or it default value from theme? You need to upload image under bottom content. Check the folder media/wysiwyg. Are you able to find the image banner_content2.jpg there? If not then please upload it.

Comment: @SukumarGorai banner_content2.jpg is in both the static block in CMS tab and in the "bottom content" section in "Theme Vast" for the category.

Comment: Is it present under media/wysiwyg directory?

Comment: @SukumarGorai It is

Comment: Can you give me the theme demo url?

Comment: @SukumarGorai http://themarket.themevast.com/furniture/index.php/

Comment: I mean demo admin if possible?